# FDT - Create a Project with existing source files, assets, folders etc

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse-plugin, fdt

I am using FDT 5 and would like to create a new project with already existing source files and assets.  When I start up the Project Wizard (New->FDT Project) I browse to the folder I want to make as the project but I cannot proceed as FDT gives me the error:

*"PROJECT_NAME overlaps the location of another project: PROJECT_NAME"*

I have downloaded a flash project (developed in FDT) and would just simply like to make it a project in my FDT environment.

I mean this shouldn't be so complicated right?  I don't want to create an entirely new project (its own folder) I want to use the same folder I downloaded and view that project.  I am using git so I have to work in the same path, sort of speak.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Apparently this is an issue with FDT, a small bug.  I managed to solve the problem following this:

[FDT / Eclipse Error : ‘overlaps the location of another project’](http://benje.tumblr.com/post/23735611907/fdt-eclipse-error-overlaps-the-location-of-another)

And on the eclipse forum:
[Eclipse Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/270705/)

Comment: Maybe use "open project" instead of "new project" then?

Comment: No go, but I found a solution.  I will edit my post which fixed the problem. It was an FDT issue.

Comment: you should answer it in an answer, not mark it as [solved] ..